# Компилятор Firebird ругается на строку в триггере

Tags: firebird, sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_before_trigger FOR MY_TABLE
BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.my_number IS NULL)
    THEN NEW.my_number = GEN_ID(MY_GENERATOR, 1);
END;
```

Ругается на шестую строку (Unexpected end of command). В чем ошибка кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET TERM || ;
CREATE TRIGGER my_before_trigger FOR MY_TABLE
BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.my_number IS NULL)
    THEN NEW.my_number = GEN_ID(MY_GENERATOR, 1);
  END ||
  SET TERM ; ||
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало!